# How can the limit $x\to0$ of a composite function $g(f(x))$ not exist when both functions have a limit $x\to0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Say $f(x) = x\sin(\pi/x)$ when $x\neq0$ and $0$ when $x=0$. $g(x) = 2$ when $x=0$ and $1$ when $x\neq0$. The limit $x\to0$ of $f(x) = 0$ and the limit $x\to0$ of $g(x) = 1$. Somehow the limit $x\to0$ of $g(f(x))$ DNE. Can someone explain why that is and how you would prove it? I got this question from [this video](https://youtu.be/y1WYANJ7IPc?si=_4n7qHKJ_ANEc-LL&t=138) the creator gave this question to do on your own but I am unable to do it.

Comment: Consider $x=\pi/n$ for any nonzero integer $n$. What is $g(f(x))$? What is $g(f(x))$ for all other values of $x$?

Comment: Remember the two versions of limit law for composition of functions: 1) if $f(x) \to b, f(x) \neq b$ as $x\to a$ and $g(x) \to L$ and $x\to b$ then $g(f(x)) \to L$ as $x\to a$ 2) if $f(x) \to b$ as $x\to a$ and $g$ is continuous at $b$ then $g(f(x)) \to g(b) $ as $x\to a$. Your example does not match hypotheses of both the versions of the limit law and hence there is no guarantee of existence of limit of $g(f(x)) $.

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer above, but the crux of the issue is that $g(x)$ is not continuous at 0, and even though $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$, there exist infinitely many points $x_n \to 0$ where $f(x_n) = 0$: these are points of the form $x_n := \frac{1}{n}$ for $n=1,2,3,...$

Further, there exist infinitely many points $y_n \to 0$ where $f(y_n) >0$, and to be explicit, we can take $y_n := \frac{1}{n+1/2}.$

Evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} g(f(x_n)) \quad \text{ and } \lim_{n \to \infty}g(f(y_n))$$
and explain why this implies $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(f(x))$ does not exist.

You should also consider why the composite function $g(x^2)$ does have a limit at $x = 0$.

Comment: I wasn't sure if they learned that, hence why I used $\epsilon-\delta$.

Comment: X Station is correct in that I have not learned this yet, in the future, I will try to specify what concepts I know so far.

Comment: Since the $x_n,y_n \to 0$, the setup is exactly what you need to use an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof but is more explicit in what is happening. The goal was for you to translate this into an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g(f(x))$ does exist and call it $L$. Since Then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x|<\delta$, then $|g(f(x))-L|<\epsilon$. Note that $g(f(x))$ is a positive function, so $L>0$ Now take $\epsilon=L$. Let $\delta_L$ be the value of $\delta$ that fulfills the criteria. Notice that $f(x)$ passes through the x-axis infinitely many times as $x\rightarrow 0$ from either side. Therefore, we can find an $x$ such that $|x|<\delta_L$ and $g(f(x))=2$. Hence, $|2-L|<L$. Now, notice that $2=|2-L+L|=|2+L-L|$. By the triangle inequality, $|2+L-L|\leq|2+L|+|-L|$ and $|2-L+L|\leq|2-L|+|L|<2L$. Thus, $|2+L|+|-L|<2L$. Since $|2+L|=2+L$ and $|-L|=L$, we have $2L+2<2L$. But this is impossible, so we have a contradiction. So no such $L$ can exist. Q.E.D